# Why am i encoutering a split brain issue in keepalived?

Tags: keepalived

When I start my BACKUP keepalived instance it also assumes the MASTER State as you can see below:

```
Mar 28 02:38:05 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[23527]: VRRP_Instance(VI_01) Entering BACKUP STATE
Mar 28 02:38:05 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[23527]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), proto(112), unicast(1), fd(10,11)]
Mar 28 02:38:05 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[23527]: VRRP_Script(check_haproxy) succeeded
Mar 28 02:38:17 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[23527]: VRRP_Instance(VI_01) Transition to MASTER STATE
Mar 28 02:38:21 localhost Keepalived_vrrp[23527]: VRRP_Instance(VI_01) Entering MASTER STATE
```

#### Master config:

```
# Script used to check if HAProxy is running
vrrp_script check_haproxy {
script "/usr/sbin/pidof haproxy"
interval 2
}
# Virtual interface
# The priority specifies the order in which the assigned interface to take over in a failover
vrrp_instance VI_01 {
state MASTER
interface eth0
advert_int 4
unicast_src_ip 10.1.2.50
unicast_peer {
        10.1.2.51
    }
virtual_router_id 51
priority 150
# The virtual ip address shared between the two loadbalancers
virtual_ipaddress {
    10.1.2.100
}
track_script {
check_haproxy
}
```

#### Backup config:

```
# Script used to check if HAProxy is running
vrrp_script check_haproxy {
script "/usr/sbin/pidof haproxy"
interval 2
}
# Virtual interface
# The priority specifies the order in which the assigned interface to take over in a failover
vrrp_instance VI_01 {
state BACKUP
advert_int 4
interface eth0
unicast_src_ip 10.1.2.51
unicast_peer {
        10.1.2.50
    }
virtual_router_id 51
priority 100
# The virtual ip address shared between the two loadbalancers
virtual_ipaddress {
    10.1.2.100
}
track_script {
check_haproxy
}
}
```

I then went onto check if the two instances were talking to each other:

#### Master

```
$ tcpdump -i eth0 'ip proto 112'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:48:33.557462 IP host1.novalocal > 10.1.2.51: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 101, authtype none, intvl 4s, length 20
02:48:37.558487 IP host1.novalocal > 10.1.2.51: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 101, authtype none, intvl 4s, length 20
02:48:41.559496 IP host1.novalocal > 10.1.2.51: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 101, authtype none, intvl 4s, length 20
```

#### Backup

```
$ tcpdump -i eth0 'ip proto 112'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:49:38.269751 IP host2.novalocal > 10.1.2.50: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 100, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
02:49:39.270461 IP host2.novalocal > 10.1.2.50: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 100, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
02:49:40.271197 IP host2.novalocal > 10.1.2.50: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 100, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
```

Any hints as to why the BACKUP instance is not recognising the MASTER?

### Update 1:

iptables results:

#### Master

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#### Backup

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Solution**

Turns out it was a firewall issue. I was able to verify this by performing `tcpdump` on the destination host to validate the adverts were received. After fixing the firewall issue I now get the vrrp adverts which were not present before. The following was run on the backup host:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 src host 10.1.2.50
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
01:06:42.709813 IP 10.1.2.50 > sntstsvmrla2a02.novalocal: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 101, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
01:06:43.709901 IP 10.1.2.50 > sntstsvmrla2a02.novalocal: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 51, prio 101, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
```

Comment: please provide a dump of your iptables config. `iptables -L`

Comment: @JohnA added, no rules are present.

Comment: It was a firewall issue, but not iptables?  Do you have a firewall between two systems on the same subnet?  I'm curious how that is set up.

Comment: I am operating inside a hosted environment where the VMs/Network require an explicit allow for the vrrp protocol in the security groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your tcpdump shows, both systems try to talk to each other, but receive no answers.  So both think the other system is down, and the backup does what it's made for.  You need to find out what's blocking communications.

Comment: Last night I got this issue, in case of network appliance temporary fault or *misbehavior* like faulty cables or electric surge on POE eth port
The result is:  DOUBLE ip address assigned and weird behavior at application level.

Is there any ARP script for detecting conflict ?

Comment: Who would be doing the detecting?  In the mean time, did you find what caused your problem?

Comment: I did not found root cause, too many variable factors, one  (but I'm still searching confirmation) could be temporary virtual networking freeze during vmware esxi Freeze snapshot, the second is VRRP link connecting dataroom 1 and dataroom 2, (I got unexpectd SPT alert in a chained procurve switch, but coud be a separate problem) in any case I think I will move on traefik + metallb which adopts K native consensus for master election.

Comment: For detection I have a separate Zabbix server for each dataroom, I added and arpscan check

Comment: I added a *mitigation* script you can see my answer below in the thread

Answer (score 0):

Just for my Environment (questionable as general purpose), I got faulty brain splitting only for transient core switch failover when SPT algo recalculate routes (up to 30 seconds) , which may happen during core switches firmware upgrade.

```
#MASTER
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy # 20 points
    }

#BACKUP
        track_script {
            chk_haproxy             # 10 points
            chk_ping_core_switch    # 10 points
            # if not core switch -> brain splitted
        }
```

using this config Backup node is not eligible of becoming Master until core switch is back to normal.